# backgrounding a process with & (ampersand) does not work in bash

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I'm trying to script tmux with a bash script.

Here's the line that I'm using to execute another script in the background (quotes are part of the line):

```
"$CURRENT_DIR/scripts/continuum_restore.sh" &
```

That works just fine on my machine. The problem is, it seems that the above line is *not backgrounded* for another user that uses the script. The script is executed synchronously in his case.
Interestingly, we tried backgrounding a random process from the login shell (`sleep 10 &`) and things worked okay in that case.

Here's a [github issue](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum/issues/1#issuecomment-75385184) the user opened.

Here's all the info I have for the user's computer where backgrounding does not seem to work:

- OSX 10.10.1
- `bash --version` is GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
- users' tmux version is `1.9a` (if this matters)

Here's the whole script that contains the line that is not backgrounded, [link](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum/blob/f821d353eade7046721ea1d2ceffc2f9c988cefe/continuum.tmux). The problematic line is 56.

Ideally I'd like to first reproduce the issue consistently and then try to fix it. Here are the things I've tried to reproduce the issue (unsuccessfully):

- `set +m` (setting this just before the line with ampersand)
- `stty susp undef` (setting this just before the line with ampersand)
- setting both of the above

The specific question I have is: what option can be used to disable backgrounding functionality in bash/shell? (so I can reproduce the above issue)

Comment: Ask the user to hit enter a few times to see if the prompt returns. People often think something runs in the foreground when it's actually just spamming the terminal from the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to redirect output. It could prevent job to run in a background.

```
nohup "$CURRENT_DIR/scripts/continuum_restore.sh" >/tmp/output.log &
```